# Permission Denied VBScript error when trying to run the file

Tags: windows-10, permissions, vbscript

So I'm trying to emulate a security related github repository using VMs and for that I had to run a VBScript.

The VBScript is as follows:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "C:\Users\Public\Java-Update.exe"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

where `Java-Update.exe` is a file that I have present within my computer.

Now I'm performing a Remote Desktop Connection from another VM, and I'm decently sure that I have logged in as an administrator, however, when I try to run the VBScript, I get the Permission Denied with error code 800A0046 error. I got this exact error even when I tried to run the script on the VM itself.

Help would be really appreciated, I'll gladly provide any information needed

Comment: Try opening a `Cmd` prompt with `Run as administrator`. Then run your VBS file from that command line. For example: `wscript Java-Update.vbs`. Does it still error?

Comment: Since all the script does is run `Java-Update.exe` why not just run that exe directly (as administrator if required)?

Comment: So, I tried it by running in cmd prompt under administrator control, but that still gave me the exact same issue.

As for your second advice, how would I run the exe file within my cmd/powershell/whatever? Since this won't fit directly into my cmd. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56117328/vbscript-error-code-800a0046-permission-denied)

Comment: So I looked at both the post and the repairwin website, and I tried out the stuff recommended at repairwin website.

When I tried to set the UAC to basically 0, nothing changed as far as I could tell. I didn't receive any warnings when I tried to run the script by doubleclicking it, but when I try to run it using cmd (in admin mode) it still gives me permission denied message.

As for running the exe as admin, when I do that I get the following error: "Windows cannot find the specified file. You may not have the appropriate permissions" (this is when I've full control for the file)

Comment: (Sorry to split this into 2 messages but ran out of characters) I ran a fresh VM and tried to run the script, and it worked, so it has to be because I'm trying to do this remotely. However, I have complete admin access to the computer, which is why I'm very confused. Also, I connected my computer to a user in a domain, and also am currently logged in as <domain_user>\<domain_name> and due to this (atleast I suspect), I'm unable to run my script even when I'm not in a remote connection.

Comment: The only way I can help further is if I can recreate the issue, but there's not enough detail in your question to do that. If you can update your question with your exact environment and steps that lead to the error, then I'm sure I could help. Otherwise, I guess you'll have to wait for someone else to come along that has done something similar and encountered the same error.